# How to get apps list in task manager windows on python?

Tags: python, windows, file, taskmanager

How to get this processes category on python? [image]
I try to get all process, but I don't now how to get only this category of processes.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import subprocess
import psutil

pids = []

cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select Id'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if line.rstrip():
        #print(line.decode().rstrip())
        pids.append(line.decode().rstrip())
pids.remove('   Id')
pids.remove('   --')

for pid in pids:
    process = psutil.Process(int(pid))
    process_name = process.name()
    print(process_name)
```

This is my answer

Comment: Please explain the solution. It's difficult to learn without an explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).